# Collation of mysql import differs when exec from php

Tags: php, mysql, bash, utf-8, collation

Good evening:

I have a php script which receives a .sql file, this script then imports it to the database and makes some changes to the data imported. It does that callling this (after moving the uploaded file):

```
shell_exec('nohup bash import.sh > import.log 2>&1 &');
```

In import.sh there is this command among others:

```
mysql -h localhost -u x -px x < file_uploaded.sql
```

When I run 'nohup bash impor.sh > import.log 2>&1 &' from console it works perfectly but when run from php script (nginx) it imports the .sql with incorrect collation appearing strange characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your input file is encoded in utf8. If not, change the encodings below appropriately.

Just a guess but maybe for scripts executed by PHP a wrong `LANG` is set or it is missing and the default is not utf-8. Try to set `LANG` explicitly in your import.sh:

```
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8" # or whatever your default locale is
mysql -h localhost -u x -px x < file_uploaded.sql
```

In addition you can try the `--default-character-set=` option for mysql:

```
mysql -h localhost -u x -px x --default-character-set=utf8 < file_uploaded.sql
```

Comment: The file had the right encoding as it worked with my user. Using `--default-character-set=utf8` worked perfeclty with any user (including www-data). Thanks so much!